# Spring Security method security not working: PreAuthorize allowing all users instead of limited users

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement method level security using spring security. I have annotated 2 separate methods with the `@PreAuthorize` annotation. In this example, I have 2 users ADMIN and USER. And I have restricted 2 methods both to each of the users. When I try logging in as USER I am able to access both the endpoint restricted to USER (`getSomeTextForUser()`) as well as to ADMIN(`getSomeTextForAdmin()`). So this is definitely not right and after viewing multiple tutorials I have not seen the error in my ways.

**Expected behavior:** person logged in as USER should get an error when trying to access the endpoint `/test/admin` since it calls `getSomeTextForAdmin()`. And the similar behavior should happen for the admin when calling `/test/user` since it calls `getSomeTextForUser()`.

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

My controller class

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return ("<h1> Welcome </h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/admin")
    public String test() {
        return getSomeTextForAdmin();
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/user")
    public String test2() {
        return getSomeTextForUser();
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String getSomeTextForAdmin() {
        return "For Admin Only!";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String getSomeTextForUser() {
        return "For User Only!";
    }

}
```

The security configuration where I've enabled the prePost feature

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin();


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }


}
```

My User details service where I've just placed some default users in memory on startup for testing.

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();

    public UserRepositoryImpl() {
        createDefaultUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName) {
        return Optional.of(users.get(userName));
    }

    private void createDefaultUsers() {
        users.put("admin", new User("admin", "pass", "ADMIN"));
        users.put("user", new User("user", "pass", "USER"));
    }
}
```

MyUserDetails is here

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final String userName;
    private final String password;

    private final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {

        this.userName = user.getUserName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the user class itself

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    public User(String userName, String password, String roles) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private String roles;


}
```

Comment: Your security config seems to be lacking an `@Configuration` annotation.

Comment: I thought that was provided with the annotation "EnableWebSecurity"? Digging into that annotation it appears it is there. Comment for this annotation: "Add this annotation to an {@code @Configuration} class to have the Spring Security configuration defined in any {@link WebSecurityConfigurer} or more likely by extending the {@link WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter} base class and overriding individual methods:"

Comment: No it isn't. It even explicitly states thaty you have to add it to an `@Configuration` class. `@EnableWebSecurity` itself isn't meta-annotated with `@Configuration`.

Comment: Ok. Must be a lack of understanding then as it has the additional annotations above the interface definition here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html.

Comment: I added configuration annotation however I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: why do you need this line in your configuration?

```
.antMatchers("/test").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
```

You don't even have `/test` endpoint in your controller.

Second thing:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return ("<h1> Welcome </h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/admin")
    public String test() {
        return getSomeTextForAdmin();
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/user")
    public String test2() {
        return getSomeTextForUser();
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String getSomeTextForAdmin() {
        return "For Admin Only!";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String getSomeTextForUser() {
        return "For User Only!";
    }

}
```

It shows you don't understand what Spring Proxy is. Unless you learn it, soon or later you will fall into problems.

I really encourge you to read about it but for now one takeaway to remember:
Annotated methods must be called from different class. In your case you call annotated methods from the same class and Spring doesn't care about any annotation.

You should use somtehing like this:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String getSomeTextForAdmin() {
        return "For Admin Only!";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String getSomeTextForUser() {
        return "For User Only!";
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return ("<h1> Welcome </h1>");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test/admin")
    public String test() {
        return userService.getSomeTextForAdmin();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test/user")
    public String test2() {
        return userService.getSomeTextForUser();
    }
}
```